# Area of a latitude-longitude rectangle looks wrong

Tags: geometry, geolocation, geospatial

I am trying to compute area of a latitude-longitude rectangle using following formula:

A = (pi/180)R^2 |sin(lat1)-sin(lat2)| |lon1-lon2|
R is earth radius (6378 kms)

(source: http://mathfax.com/area-of-a-latitude-longitude-rectangle/)
Derivation of the formula at above url seems correct.

But using this formula to compute area for small/medium cities gives a much larger result.
For example: Bounding box of Mountain View, CA 
(Source: maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=mountain%20view,%20california&sensor=false)
is (37.3565410, -122.1178620) - (37.4698870, -122.0446720)
Plugging these values in the formula shows an area of 5647 sq.km, that is too large.
Actual area is 32 sq.km. Bounding box area should not be too far off.

What is wrong with this calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the latitudes and longitudes into radians before calling sin.

Comment: Note that in the formula longitudes are already converted to radians (because of the pi/180 factor) though.